# How to remove a tkinter label after a specified amount of time?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

In my tkinter page i want a button that makes a label appear and after 3-5 seconds it dissapears.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button
import pyautogui

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300, relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()

def get_square_root():
    
    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Complete', font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 275, window=label3)
    

def on_click():
   label3.after(1000, label3.destroy())


button1 = tk.Button(text='Submit', command=lambda: [get_square_root(), on_click()], bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=button1)



root.mainloop()
```

Tried adding 2 functions to fit in 1 command however when running it python refuses to show the label at all.

Comment: it needs to be `label3.after(1000, label4.destroy)`.

Comment: "Refuses to show the label"  but your question is about how to remove a label. If the label doesn't show isn't it what you want?

Comment: I want the label to appear and dissapear, however after combining 2 functions in 1 command, python doesnt display the label anymore after the button is clicked

Comment: `label3` is a local variable inside `get_square_root()`, so it cannot be accessed inside `on_click()`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
label3.after(1000, label4.destroy)
```

Thank you Bryan Oakley

Edit:

I finally made it so the labels being undefined by just adding the items in each function to 1 function

```py
def one_command():

    label4 = tk.Label(root, text='Complete', font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 275, window=label4)

    label4.after(1000, label4.destroy)






button1 = tk.Button(text='Submit', command=one_command, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=button1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also changed label name from label3 to label4

Answer (score 0):

you can import sleep from time library
type sleep(s) the s prameter is time in seconde
and use yourlablename.destroy()
example:

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
app=Tk()
lbl=Lable(app,text="hello")
lbl.pack()
sleep(10)
lbl.destroy()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see `Label3` on fly. Actually, you are missing `labe3.pack()`

> Tried adding 2 functions to fit in 1 command however when running it
> python refuses to show the label at all

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button
 

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300, relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Complete', font=('helvetica', 10))
label3.pack()

def get_square_root():
    canvas1.create_window(200, 275, window=label3)
    

def on_click():
   label3.after(1000, label3.destroy())
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Submit', command=lambda: [get_square_root(), on_click()], bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Output before you see `Label`:

[image]

Output after `Label` is disappeared:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, this button is a 1 time use however this may help me in the future.

Thanks